# How to select max value for each id in sql select statement?

Tags: mysql, select, max

Consider these two tables.

First Table

---

stageTable

stageId-----stageName

1-----------Start

2-----------Planning

3-----------Working

4-----------Review

5-----------Closing

---

Second Table

---

stageProject

stageid-------projectId

1-------------1

2-------------1

3-------------1

4-------------1

1-------------2

2-------------2

3-------------2

4-------------2

5-------------2

1-------------3

2-------------3

3-------------3

---

What i want to do is from each projectId, i want to get the max stageId value

So i want to end up with:

1-4

2-5

3-3

and assign the stageName from the stage table so the final result would be

projectId-----max-----stageName

1            4           review

2            5            closing

3            3            working

I've tried with

```
select a.projectid, max(a.stageid), b.stageName
from stageProject a, stageTable b
where a.stageId=b.stageId
group by a.projectId
```

but it does not work

i end with the correct stageId and max but the stageName is always the same

Can you help me out !

Comment: I'm not too sure with this syntax if the `WHERE` clause will apply to the query itself or will be the condition for the join.. have you tried explicitely using `ON` for the join? - edit. seems right this way.

Comment: Thank you! I guess there is not only one way, i see that Lluis got it right on spot too. Thank you guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT a.projectId,a.maxStageId,b.stageName
FROM (SELECT projectId,max(stageId) as maxStageId
      FROM stageProject 
      GROUP BY 1 ) a
INNER JOIN stageTable b ON a.maxStageId = b.stageId;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4657/10)</kbd>

This will get the max stageID for each projectID, then take those results and do an inner join with stageTable to get their names.

Should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select distinct projectid, 
       (select max(stageid) 
        from  stageProject p2
        where p1.projectId = p2.projectId),
       (selec stageName from stageTable 
        where stageId = (select max(stageid) 
                         from stageProject p2
                         where p1.projectId = p2.projectId))
from stageProject p1
```

or this

```
select ps.projectid, ps.stageid, st.stagename
from stageTable st, 
      (select a.projectid, max(a.stageid) stageid
       from stageProject a, stageTable b
       where a.stageId=b.stageId
       group by a.projectId) ps
where st.stageid = ps.stageid
```